# Load javascript file outside of application.js & pipeline in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have page1, page2 and page3 in my Rails application.

For page2 I have a special javascript file with some jQuery .click events.

I include the file to my application.js `//= require specialfile`
The specialfile is in my app/assets/javascripts/specialfile.js path.

I figured out that if I will go from page1 or page3 to the page2, the special js file doesn't work unless I will refresh the page. It works only if I will go directly to the page2 without any previous move.

I tried not to require the specialfile.js in my application.js pipeline and include it directly to my page2 by: `<%= javascript_include_tag "specialfile" %>`. It didn't work. I also tried to add there the full path like assets/javascript/specialfile.js ... app/assets/javascript/specialfile but no luck.

How can I do it?

I found something like: `<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if AppName::Application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.js") %>` but I don't understand well. How I can point to the specialfile?

Comment: In Page1 & Page2, when `view page source`, do you see `specialfile.js` file?

Comment: What you mean? If I have it in my application.js, it works everywhere, but there is an issue with this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/script-not-running-unless-i-refresh-page ... If I try to point on it with the javascript_include_tag "specialfile.js" it will show 404 not found in the console.

Comment: If it's loaded but didn't work, please consider `turbolinks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Rails includes the [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic) gem, which loads just the `body` of the page when you click on a link without doing a full load of the whole page. Because it's no longer doing a full reload of the page, the "ready" event on `document` is not triggered.

You should read the turbolinks README, [especially this bit on Events](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#events) for more information, but generally the quick way around this is instead of your code being in a `$(...` or `$(document).ready` block you should put it in:

```
$(document).on("ready page:load", ...
```